# Как правильно писать аргументы к методу Main в Java

Tags: java

Как правильно писать аргументы к методу Main? Мой друг изучает java и пишет `public static void Main(String args[])`, хотя я пишу `public static void Main(String[] args)` (но на C#). Не можем решить этот спор уже где-то 2 месяца. Недавно я зашёл на сайт онлайн компилятора для java и там было написано `public static void Main(String[] args)`

Comment: Чем  отличается String args[] от String[] args?

Comment: а почему вы вообще решили сравнить конструкции из разных языков по этому признаку?

Comment: @Эникейщик, расположением `[]` очевидно :)

Comment: Нехорошо удалять свои вопросы, на которые вам ответили. Зачем вы это сделали с [вопросом про кодировку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/967499/213987)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Мой друг изучает java и пишет public static void Main(String args[]),
>   хотя я пишу public static void Main(String[] args) (но на C#).

Во-первых, в `Java` должна объявляться функция `main`, а не `Main`. А в `C#` класс строк называется `string`, а не `String` (если вы не используете using директив).

Согласно документации Java одно из этих объявлений `main` может быть использовано

```
public static void main(String[] args)
public static void main(String... args)
```

Из спецификации языка Java 11 (12.1.4 Invoke Test.main)

> The method main must be declared public, static, and void. It must
>   specify a formal parameter (§8.4.1) whose declared type is array of
>   String. Therefore, either of the following declarations is acceptable:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
public static void main(String... args)
```

Так как переменные типа массива в Java могут объявляться двояко как

```
String[] s;
```

так и

```
String s[];
```

то, в принципе, вы также можете объявить метод `main` в `Java` и как

```
public static void main(String args[] )
```

Кстати сказать, в `C#` метод `Main` не обязательно должен быть объявлен как `public` в отличии от `Java`, где метод `main` должен быть `public`.

Comment: _в C# класс строк называется string, а не String_ - там же string алиас для String, то есть они взаимозаменяемы

Comment: @Grundy Не совсем так. Вы забываете про пространства имен.

Comment: В любом случае в C# вполне себе класс [`String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Grundy Опять-таки, это зависит от using директив и пространств имен.

Comment: Да, я потом увидел правку про пространства имен. Если точнее `string` -> `System.String`.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы будете использовать **IntelliJ IDEA**, то сможете использовать специальную горячую команду "*psvm*", которая объявляет главный класс.
Единственный правильный способ написания в **Java** аргументов к методу **main**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

}
```

Тем не менее, разницы между `String[] args` и `String args[]` нет, просто есть общепринятые правила написания.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы желаете ознакомиться с правилами написания кода на Java, прикрепляю для вас `Java Code Conventions.` (Предупреждаю, она на английском) https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Comment: То, о чем я и говорил, есть правила и их нужно выполнять даже если работает и без них.